# I got json exception phone registration error when getting device token

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins

I am using ionic push notification with google cloud messaging. But I did not get device token. I got json exception phone registration error.

Here I captured the error:

[image]

Comment: what version of cordova plugin are you using?

Comment: Can you show your code? especially on how you call your register function. While you are on it, check this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/push-notifications-in-ionic-apps-with-google-cloud-messaging/) about Push Notifications in Ionic Apps with Google Cloud Messaging